# Is ARIMA the wrong approach or am I missing something?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I am predicting a time series by splitting the prediction model in a deterministic linear regressive part and a stochastic part. The data was split into a training set of 2190 timesteps and a test set of 730 timesteps. The deterministic part is a linear model in the form of:

> [image]

The linear part consists of around 18 predictor variables and works well, displaying sufficient prediction accuracy over the future test set. Following an approach by [Sotiropoulos et al. (2013)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6672834), the residuals of the linear model can be described by an ARIMA model. This would result in the complete model in the form of:

> [image]

with s(t) being an ARIMA model. With the *auto.arima()* function of R followed by a grid search, I determined two possible ARIMA models. One with external regressors and one without. Please see the output of *checkresiduals()* for the best fitting ARIMA without regressors below:

> [image: ARIMA 1]

so far everything looks as it should. The problem is that the ARIMA model performs very bad in predicting the future test set. To predict the future values I have used:

*forecast(model,h=730,biasadj=FALSE)*, 
*simulate(model,n=730)* and 
*predict(model,n.ahead=730,se.fit=FALSE)*.

Please see the results below:

> ##### ARIMA forecast without external regressors
>
> [image: ARIMA forecasts comparison]

The mean of the forecast() output is continuously at zero, therefore I thought adding external regressors might help. I added as many external regressors from the predictor values as possible, refitting another ARIMA. But I still get a very bad prediction accuracy:

> ##### ARIMA forecast with external regressors
>
> [image: ARIMA forecast with external regressors]

In all cases, the predicted residuals of the deterministic part within the test set have higher errors than the deterministic part itself, while for the training set the ARIMA model describes the deterministic residuals very well.

Is there something I am missing? Maybe the functions I used were not suited?
From my mathematical understanding of ARIMAS I think a possible solution would be to increase q to something very high like 60 or so, but that would only help for the first predicted 60 values I guess. Are ARIMAS just not suited for long term predictions?

##### What else have I tried?

I simulated the ARIMA series for 20000 times and checked, if by chance, a fitting series would be generated but all 20000 tries had a worse prediction accuracy than just leaving the deterministic residuals on their own.

To see if maybe the ARIMA model was overfit to the training period I used the test period as training period and tried to predict the test period with it, but had similar unsatisfying results. So the problem is not a bad ARIMA model, but rather how I ask it to produce future values.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Hi, did you check for seasonality? Is this hourly, weekly, or monthly data? It might be useful information in answering this question. Additionally, maybe you can tell at least what the y variable is, electricity price or something?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. The data granularity is daily, the training set of 2190 values equals 6 years and the test set is 2 years (730 days). The y variable is a bit complicated. It is the difference of average hourly energy consumption of the respective day to the average hourly consumption per year. If we have an average hourly consumption of 10000 MWh in 2014 and on 2nd December 2014 the daily average is 12000 MWh y would be 2000 MWh. I think the ACF plot of the ARIMA residuals showing no autocorrelation should exclude seasonality, but I might be wrong.